# SQL Server Converts rows to columns dynamic columns

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have the following table

family

```
id     name
-------------
1      Joe

1      Jim

1      Jane

2      Matt

2      Pat

3      Gary
```

---

3      Mike

Would like to get to

```
id     name1,   name2,   name3, name4 ....

1      Joe      Jim      Jane

2      Matt     Pat

3      Gary     Mike.
```

Can this be done using PIVOT?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c5e5b/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Test_TABLE(id INT, name VARCHAR(10))
GO

INSERT INTO Test_TABLE VALUES 
(1 ,'Joe'),(1 ,'Jim'),(1 ,'Jane'),
(2 ,'Matt'),(2 ,'Pat'),(3 ,'Gary')
GO
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT *
           ,'Name' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID ASC) AS VARCHAR(3)) Names
    FROM Test_TABLE )t
PIVOT (MAX(Name)
       FOR Names
       IN (Name1,Name2,Name3)
      )p
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c5e5b/1/0)**:

```
| ID | NAME1 |  NAME2 |  NAME3 |
|----|-------|--------|--------|
|  1 |   Joe |    Jim |   Jane |
|  2 |  Matt |    Pat | (null) |
|  3 |  Gary | (null) | (null) |
```